# Is there a generating set of $\mathbb{Z}^3$ having cardinality $2$?

Tags: group-theory

> Is there a generating set of $\mathbb{Z}^3$ having cardinality $2$?

I believe that the answer is no...

I looked over at possible generating sets, such as $<(1,1,0),(0,1,1)>$, and I can see that there are elements which can't be represented using that set, as since  $\mathbb{Z}^3$ can have $3$ different elements, the generating set must be of at least $3$ elements...

And yet, I'm not sure, how to prove this formally?

Comment: No. Such a set would be a basis of $\mathbb{Z}^3 \otimes \mathbb{Q} = \mathbb{Q}^3$.

Comment: It is well known that $\Bbb R^3$ is a three-dimensional vector space.  Any subset of $\Bbb Z^3$ which is generated by two elements will necessarily be a subset of the subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ generated by those two elements, and is therefore a subset of only a two-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^3$, a third dimension being left entirely untouched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppse that such a set $\{v,w\}$ exists. Then there are numbers $a,a',a'',b,b',b''\in\mathbb Z$ such that$$(1,0,0)=av+bw,\ (0,1,0)=a'v+b'w,\text{ and }(0,0,1)=a''v+b''w.$$But since $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,0)\}$ are $3$ linearly independent elements of $\mathbb{Q}^3$, this would mean that $\mathbb{Q}^3$, which is a $3$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb Q$, would have a generating set with two elements. That is impossible.

Answer (score 9):

One trick is to consider the images of your would-be generators
in $G=\Bbb Z^3/2\Bbb Z^3$. Then $G$ is a vector space of dimension $3$
over $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ and cannot be generated by two generators.

Comment: clever! $+1 \dots$